# Spring @ModelAttribute doesn't care about commandName

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="editWeather" method="post" action="../edit">
    <!-- Input fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

And this is how I get the model in Spring:

```
@ModelAttribute("DONTGIVEADAMN") Weather weather
```

And I can still use the `weather` to do my operations and it works great, for example:

```
weatherService.editWeather(weather);
```

My question is...Why does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model attribute name doesn't matter when binding data received from a form (because names of form fields correspond to the names of fields of the model object), it matters only when rendering a form.

I particular, when model attribute name in your `POST` handler method doesn't match the `commandName` in the form, you will be able to receive the data, but won't be able to redisplay a form with validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

its matching the class type (or interface), not the name of the variable/parameter; and the specified request mapping/method signature must be correct.